# Is a block's prev hash stored as an attribute or calculated every time you validate it?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

In some references,I found that a block's prev hash would be stored in its head part once it was mined.But in [blockchain demo](https://demoblockchain.org/blockchain),when I changed some data of a block,the following blocks' prev hash changed automatically,it seems the prev hash is not stored,but calculated every time.So which is to be true?

Answer (score 0):

> *when I changed some data of a block,the following blocks' prev hash changed automatically*

In most blockchain systems, other peers of the network reject change proposals to already included blocks.

So for example in Ethereum, a block producer creates a block #2, and includes the previous block (#1) hash in headers of #2. The block #2 is accepted by other peers after it's further validated that it follows all other rules of the network. If the same peer or anyone else tries to resubmit the (already accepted) block #2 with some changes, other peers reject it.

So the previous block hash can be stored in the header, as it's not expected to change.

Comment: Thx.As you said"In most blockchain systems, other peers of the network reject change proposals to already included blocks",but how do other peers check if there are some blocks changed?By checking the last block's hash or all blocks' hash?Put it another way,suppose there're n blocks,is the check algorithm O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: @LeslieJiang Complexity to initially sync a node is O(n). Real-life scenario, when you just installed a new node client software, the initial sync takes couple hours to couple days... After the node is fully synced, complexity of validating the latest block is O(1), because you just validate whether the "latest block hash" in their submitted new block is the same as "latest block hash" in your record (and if the block contains all required fields, if the block producer reward is of expected value, etc.).